# MemoryCache's SlidingExpiration - Optionally slide expiration?

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

I'm working with [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx).

I've created the cache and have added an entry to it using a sliding expiration of 5 minutes:

```
MemoryCache.Default.Set("Key", "Value", new CacheItemPolicy
{
    SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
});
```

This entry will be removed from the cache if it is not accessed within 5 minutes. If it is accessed then the sliding expiration timer is reset back to 5 minutes:

```
// Resets the sliding expiration:
MemoryCache.Default.Get("Key");
```

I would like to be able to optionally retrieve the entry from the cache without resetting the sliding expiration timer.

It does not appear to be possible, but I'd like to confirm.

---

For clarification on my specific needs:

- I have two entities, Report and ReportData. ReportData is slow to query. Both Report and ReportData are cached into two separate MemoryCaches.
- The Report MemoryCache expires after four days. The ReportData MemoryCache expires after 30 minutes.
- Whenever ReportData naturally expires it is automatically refreshed and re-cached. This ensures that all ReportData entries are fresh.
- If a Report is not requested by a user within 4 days it is removed from the cache and its corresponding ReportData is removed, as well. Whenever a Report is requested by a user then this 4 days timer should restart.

**The issue is:** refreshing ReportData requires a reference to Report. Fetching a reference to Report via its cache causes the cache timer to restart. This is not desired. The Report cache timer should only restart when the Report is requested by a user.

A potential solution is to introduce a third cache. Another cache would allow for different expiration behaviors for external vs internal access.

Here is my current code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A service for caching Custom reports.
/// </summary>
public class ReportCachingService : ServiceBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Refresh report data every N minutes.
    /// </summary>
    private int ReportDataRefreshInterval { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remember reports for N days.
    /// </summary>
    private int MaxReportAge { get; set; }
    private MemoryCache ReportDataCache { get; set; }
    private MemoryCache ReportCache { get; set; }
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public ReportCachingService()
    {
        Logger.Info("ReportCachingService initializing...");
        LoadConfiguration();
        // Note: The name 'ReportDataCache' must be kept in-sync w/ App.config namedCache entry.
        ReportDataCache = new MemoryCache("ReportDataCache");
        ReportCache = new MemoryCache("ReportCache");
        Logger.Info("ReportCachingService successfully started.");
    }

    public ReportData GetReportData(int reportID)
    {
        string key = reportID.ToString();
        ReportData reportData = ReportDataCache.Get(key) as ReportData ?? GetAndCacheReportData(reportID);

        return reportData;
    }

    public Report GetReport(int reportID)
    {
        string key = reportID.ToString();
        Report report = ReportCache.Get(key) as Report ?? GetAndCacheReport(reportID);

        return report;
    }

    private void LoadConfiguration()
    {
        try
        {
            ReportDataRefreshInterval = GetConfigValue("ReportDataRefreshInterval");
            MaxReportAge = GetConfigValue("MaxReportAge"); ;
            Logger.Info(string.Format("Configuration loaded. Report data will refresh every {0} minutes. Maximum report age is {1} day(s).", ReportDataRefreshInterval, MaxReportAge));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error loading configuration.", exception);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static int GetConfigValue(string key)
    {
        string configValueString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configValueString))
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to find {0} in App.config", key));
        }

        int configValue;
        bool isValidConfigValue = int.TryParse(configValueString, out configValue);

        if (!isValidConfigValue)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} was found in App.config, but is not a valid integer value.", key));
        }

        return configValue;
    }

    private ReportData GetAndCacheReportData(int reportID)
    {
        Report report = GetReport(reportID);
        ReportData reportData = report.GetData(false, "Administrator");

        if (reportData == null)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format("Failed to find reportData for report with ID: {0}", reportID);
            Logger.Error(errorMessage);
            throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        }

        // SlidingExpiration forces cache expiration to refresh when an entry is accessed.
        TimeSpan reportDataCacheExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, ReportDataRefreshInterval, 0);
        string key = reportID.ToString();
        ReportDataCache.Set(key, reportData, new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            SlidingExpiration = reportDataCacheExpiration,
            UpdateCallback = OnReportDataUpdate
        });

        return reportData;
    }

    private Report GetAndCacheReport(int reportID)
    {
        // If the ReportCache does not contain the Report - attempt to load it from DB.
        Report report = Report.Load(reportID);

        if (report == null)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format("Failed to find report with ID: {0}", reportID);
            Logger.Error(errorMessage);
            throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        }

        // SlidingExpiration forces cache expiration to refresh when an entry is accessed.
        TimeSpan reportCacheExpiration = new TimeSpan(MaxReportAge, 0, 0, 0);
        string key = reportID.ToString();
        ReportCache.Set(key, report, new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            SlidingExpiration = reportCacheExpiration,
            RemovedCallback = OnReportRemoved
        });

        return report;
    }

    private void OnReportRemoved(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
    {
        Logger.DebugFormat("Report with ID {0} has expired with reason: {1}.", arguments.CacheItem.Key, arguments.RemovedReason);
        // Clear known ReportData for a given Report whenever the Report expires.
        ReportDataCache.Remove(arguments.CacheItem.Key);
    }

    private void OnReportDataUpdate(CacheEntryUpdateArguments arguments)
    {
        Logger.DebugFormat("ReportData for report with ID {0} has updated with reason: {1}.", arguments.UpdatedCacheItem.Key, arguments.RemovedReason);
        // Expired ReportData should be automatically refreshed by loading fresh values from the DB.
        if (arguments.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired)
        {
            int reportID = int.Parse(arguments.Key);
            GetAndCacheReportData(reportID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want by using memory caching this way. See my code below.

Comment: This is possible.  What you are seeing here is the behaviour of SlidingExpiration. You have to use AbsoluteExpiration instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old questions but I ran into a very similar problem where the `SlidingExpiration` resets every time I do a `Get(key)` which I do not want.

The answer to the original question is **no**, you cannot use a `Get(key)` without resetting the `SlidingExpiration` window.  A codding solution is required to get around this based on each specific situation.

In my case, I gave up on using the `MemoryCache` and created variables for the value and the last update time that I set and reset manually based on business logic.

Answer (score -2):

It's better to use a separate class for memory caching. Here is a sample.

```
public class MyMemoryCache
{
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache;

    public MyMemoryCache()
    {
        _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an object from cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheKey"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Get(string cacheKey)
    {
        return _cache.Get(cacheKey);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// check if the object is available in the cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheKey"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Contains(string cacheKey)
    {
        return _cache.Contains(cacheKey);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an objct in to the cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectToBeChached"></param>
    /// <param name="cacheKey"></param>
    public void Add(string cacheKey, object objectToBeChached)
    {
        var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5.0) };
        _cache.Add(cacheKey, objectToBeChached, cacheItemPolicy);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this help my issue. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have you looked at the [msdn sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)? You missed MemoryCache.Default. You also need to set an expiration policy.

Comment: I've read the entirety of the MSDN entry for MemoryCache before posting. The first code snippet in my post references MemoryCache.Default as example pseudo-code, but my full code sample builds explicit MemoryCache objects without using the default cache.

Regardless... my question is in reference to SlidingExpiration interactions which is not related to whether I'm using the default cache or my own..

Comment: Why are you using SlidingExpiration ? Once you know the answer to that question, you will have your answer, or else, you can simply try my code. :)

Comment: The down vote was for completely misinterpreting my question and posting a boilerplate response. AbsoluteExpiration does nothing like what I need. All you did was copy/paste from MSDN and ask me if I had read it. Reciprocating a downvote on a properly worded question is also pretty immature.